# 'passwd' directly escalates user

Tags: linux, security, centos

When I try to change my password with `passwd`, it directly su to the root, how was that be possible?

```
[fingal@cs-linux ~]$ passwd
[root@cs-linux fingal]#
```

I was using CentOS 6.7, and the account was even not in sudoers file, Can anyone please come up some idea how would this happen? And is there anyway could fix it?

Comment: Can you check `type -a passwd`, `rpm -Vf $(which passwd)`, `cat /etc/pam.d/passwd`, etc.?